# How to prevent additional re-renders due to params on NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, next.js, framer-motion

I'm setting up a generic loading strategy for NextJS apps using framer-motion.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
    const [isFirstMount, setIsFirstMount] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleRouteChange = () => {
            setIsFirstMount(false);
        };

        router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);

        // If the component is unmounted, unsubscribe
        // from the event with the `off` method:
        return () => {
            router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);
        };
    }, [router]);
    console.log("My App ran");
    return (
        <Layout>
            <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
                <motion.div exit={{ opacity: 0 }}>
                    {isFirstMount && <InitialTransition />}
                    <motion.div
                        initial="initial"
                        animate="animate"
                        variants={content(isFirstMount)}
                        className="space-y-12"
                    >
                        <Component
                            isFirstMount={isFirstMount}
                            key={router.route}
                            {...pageProps}
                        />
                    </motion.div>
                </motion.div>
            </AnimatePresence>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

I ran into an issue with params. When using params during initial loading (such as clicking on the refresh button on browser), NextJS loads an additional time. I believe its due to NextJS's router query object update. For example,

```
WEBSITE.com/ // works - you will see the black loading screen, the black loading screens slides down, and the child objects start popping on
// vs
WEBSITE.com/?test=test // fails - you will see the black loading screen flash in and out of view before the rest of the app proceeds
```

I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-page-transition-o75wk?file=/pages/_app.js:221-1162) sample. On the browser side, test by adding or removing `?test=test` to the end of the url.

**How can I prevent the additional re-render or get the loader to work the same way regardless of having a param or not?**

---

Update

I tried @Mokhtar 's code. Technically, it did nothing yet the transitioning started worked. Eventually I figured out that removing all the `isFirstMount` and `useEffect` logic would make the transitioning correctly.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
    console.log("My App ran");
    return (
        <Layout>
            <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
                <motion.div exit={{ opacity: 0 }}>
                    <InitialTransition />
                    <motion.div
                        initial="initial"
                        animate="animate"
                        variants={content(true)}
                    >
                        <Component key={router.route} {...pageProps} />
                    </motion.div>
                </motion.div>
            </AnimatePresence>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

**Does anyone know why its working?** I thought the exit opacity / sliding action only works when the Component is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<InitialTransition />` component is getting unmounted because of your route being called with a shallow change (https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing) and therefore calling your `handleRouteChange` handler.

The following `handleRouteChange` implementation should fix it.

```
const handleRouteChange = (url, { shallow }) => {
  if (shallow && !isFirstMount) {
    setIsFirstMount(false);
  }
};
```

Comment: Somehow its working on the codesandbox example but this doesn't make sense since `isFirstMount` never changes to false. The `!isFirstMount` prevents `setIsFirstMount` from being called.

Comment: I confirmed it by completely commenting out the useEffect and it still works. Weird.